# Should I be saving persistent data from the host activity or its fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, persistent-storage

This is more of a structure/design philosophy question than anything.

I have main host activity that currently saves and loads profiles for viewing by the user.
The profiles' credentials are displayed within Fragment A (user name, birthday, etc). This is done by passing the profile as an argument to the fragment before using the fragment transaction to display it.

If the user leaves or rotates their screen, how should I go about saving that profile data? Should I do the saving from the onPause within Fragment A or its HostActivity?

And what if Fragment A also allows for profile editing? When the user confirms their changes, shall I let its HostActivity know to update the main profile being held from the activity?

Or would it be better to just wait until a FragmentA.onPause is called? I suppose I could wait until something forces the fragment to call onPause, at which point I can save both the state of the fragment as well as the profile activity from the host activity.

**The main thing that confuses me is: Do I need to be managing two Profile objects? The HostActivity and its FragmentA both use it. It gets a bit confusing having to run back and forth between saving, loading, and editing. Can't I just handle all of this from one class?**

Okay, I have two very good and viable answers. Which one is better for my purposes though? Should I use an sqlLite database or a global Java singleton to handle my profile? Only one profile can be active per session. Saving, loading, and editing of the profile must also be taken into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can only ever be one profile per user in one session (as you have suggested above) why not use a `Java singleton class`.

```
 private ProfileOject() {
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
}

public static ProfileObject getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new ProfilerObject();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Now use getters and setters as normal.

In each activity you can get the `Profile` like so:

```
profile = ProfileObject.getInstance();
```

This will mean that if you make an update in `Fragment A`, when the `activity` is called, it will fetch the updated values from the `profile object`.

In regards to `onRotate/Pause/Resume` use `savedInstanceState`, see example below:

```
//Use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and onRestoreInstanceState

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.   
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is  
  // killed and restarted.

  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);  
  // etc.  
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  
}  
//onRestoreInstanceState  
    @Override  
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);  
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.  
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.  
  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");  
}
```

Comment: This is also a viable option. Can you tell me how using a singleton might be better than using a SQLite database?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran it means the data will be in the app so quicker to access as opposed to in a database (if remote then will take considerably longer to access) if local then maybe faster but I havent ever used a db like that so I wouldnt be the best to ask for advice. Personally I see it as quicker to use a `singleton class` as you dont have to write any `SQL` and for your scenario above it seems that it may be simpler too. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for more information on storage from the android dev guide

Comment: I have decided to use your method, since only one profile can be active at a time. Profiles can be saved/loaded locally or via the cloud, but only one at a time. I WILL, however, use SQLite for another part of my application, which will truly require a database. So thank you for that suggestion, @rosorio. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a sqlite database for storing user profile data? Everytime you need access to user  profile data you can just query it.

You can save all the relevant data in the onPause method. Using a database will ensure data persistence, resisting any fragment/activity recreation!

Comment: Yes you should save the data in the onPause of fragment A. You should also load the data when needed inside fragment A as this is the place where you display the profiles to the user.

Comment: I see. Can you tell me how using an SQLite database might be better than using a singleton?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran The main question here is: Do you want the profile data to persist between application restarts? If so use an SQLite database. If not go for the Singleton as it's implementation is much simpler and the data will only be stored while the application is running!

Comment: "the data will only be stored while the application is running" --can't you also just do a FileOutputStream and save the Singleton yourself? That will also make it persist, right?